# SQL update table when condition from another row

Tags: mysql, sql, prestashop

how to add together this schema?

```
update ps_product_shop set price.2=price.1/25.5 where id_product = *the_same* 
price.1 -> id_shop=1
price.2 -> id_shop=2
id_product -> the same for both shops
```

It is in prestashop, table with prices. In table ps_product_shop, I have on row1 id_shop = 1 and ond row2 id_shop=2

I need to update my prices for two different currency shops.

Take "price" from id_shop=1, divide it 25.5 (CZK / EUR) and set it to price for id_shop=2

I was several years before Oracle db administrator, but I am out of ths bussiness now... :)

Thank you. Komanche

update:
it is mysql, I tagged it MySQL in the thread start...

in the table,

row....id_product....id_shop....price

row1...12............1..........500

row2...12............2..........8

I need to update row 2 with price/25.5

Comment: please take some more time to refine the question. Checking typos and including the schema in a human-friendly way would be a nice start :). Additionally would be nice to  specify which DB server is...

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: why are you commenting it when you don't want to help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this below query in MySql. As the id_product will be same for both shops, join query needs to be used inside update query.

```
update ps_product_shop pps1 join ps_product_shop pps2
on pps1.id_product = pps2.id_product
set pps2.price = pps1.price/25.5 where pps2.id_shop='2';
```

Comment: Yeah you can add this.. "and pps2.id_product = '12' " for testing

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `join`.  If I understand correctly:

```
update ps_product_shop ps2 join
       ps_product_shop ps1
       on ps1.id_product = ps2.id_product and
          ps1.id_shop = 1 and ps2.id_shop = 2
    set ps2.price = ps1.price / 25.5;
```

This assumes that there is one row per shop/product combination.

Comment: in the table,
row....id_product....id_shop....price //
row1...12............1..........500 //
row2...12............2..........8 //

I need to update row 2 with price/25.5

Comment: On 3rd row, shouldn't it be ps1.id_product instead of ps.id_product?